# Mailchimp repeatable content variations are dissappearing when creating campaign

Tags: templates, html-email, mailchimp

My template is reduced to only one content block when I try to create a campaign from it.

When I edit the template I see this, 3 content blocks: 
[image: All the repeatable variations are there]

When I create a campaign from it, all the content dissappears except the first element: 
[image: Only the first repeatable variation is visible]

This is not supposed to happen, and does not happen in any default mailchimp templates. Currently we are forced to avoid having repeatable content in our templates, which makes it alot harder for the marketing department to create new campaigns.

I can duplicate the element and change the variation type of each until my entire template is back, **however this is obviously just an example, my real template is much more complicated and doing this every time would be a hassle.**

This is my code, as you can see **the repeatable content is not nested within antoher repeatable** and the variations and editable areas **all have unique names**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;" />
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
   <body>


    <div mc:repeatable="content" mc:variant="Headline">
        <h1 mc:edit="headline">Headline</h1>
    </div>

    <div mc:repeatable="content" mc:variant="Text">
        <p mc:edit="text">Introduction</p>
    </div>

    <div mc:repeatable="content" mc:variant="Image">
        <img mc:edit="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Placeholder" border="0" />
    </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
To clarify, we can give each content block a unique repeatable name `mc:repeatable="content1"` etc., and remove the variant attribute. Then everything appears, and we can duplicate any element.

However we won't be able to change the order of the elements. We can duplicate the image and change the order of the images, but we can never place an image above the headline, or text below the images. Each "content variation" is locked in place, this is what we are trying to solve.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? If I create a campaign from a template, set up all variations; resave that instance to a template and recreate it again, it also does not work (i get duplicates of all modules).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to give each repeatable a unique name, and then follow the instructions provided by Mailchimp:

> Repeatable and variable content blocks can be moved vertically within a template. After you repeat a content block, you'll see arrows in the top-left corner that you can click to drag the block up or down.

[image: And,]

> When you click on the arrow to move the block, you'll see a blue bar that can be dragged and positioned where you'd like the content block to move. You can only drag and drop a content block inside the area of the layout that it's coded into. For example, it wouldn't be possible to move a block from the right column into the left column, or from the body to the header.

From: https://mailchimp.com/help/repeatable-or-variable-content-blocks/